# Setting initial window size for a usercontrol with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Newbie question. I am using a simple dialog to display some of my usercontrols:

```
 <Window x:Class="Nova5.UI.Views.WindowDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WindowDialog" 
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="{Binding WindowState, Mode=TwoWay}" >

    <ContentPresenter x:Name="DialogPresenter" Content="{Binding .}"/>

</Window>
```

For some of my usercontrols that are hosted by the WindowDialog, I would like to have the initial dialog use SizeToContent instead of WindowState. The effect I'm trying to get is to have some user controls maximize to the entire screen, while others are to be smaller in the center of the screen.

Can this be done with the single WindowDialog or should I simply use two different WindowDialog's? (e.g., WindowDialogMaximized, and WindowDialogToContent)

Is there a better way?

Thank you for your consideration of my question.

Comment: Having an application resize itself is bad user experience.  You should probably avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create another binding for `SizeToContent` and bind the two properties like this:

- For controls that should be sized to content, set `SizeToContent` to `Width`/`Height`/`WidthAndHeight` and `WindowState` to `Normal`.
- For controls that should be maximized, set `SizeToContent` to `Manual` and `WindowState` to `Maximized`.